# The negative definiteness by deleting row and column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider a square matrix A. The matrix B is generated by deleting the k-th row and k-th column of A. Is it true to say if A is negative definite then B is negative definite too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true. This is because $A$ is negative-definite iff

$$\tag{1}\forall X \in \mathbb{R^n} \ \ X^TAX \le 0.$$

Deleting the $k$th line and column amounts to restrict (1) to vectors $X$ having a $0$ value as their $k$th coordinate, thus still true.